# OpenGL ES 2.0 Per Fragment Lighting for Untextured Generated Geometry

Tags: opengl-es, shader, opengl-es-2.0

I'm currently generating geometry rather than importing it as a model. This makes it necessary to calculate all normals within the application.

I've implemented Gouraud shading (per vertex lighting) successfully, and now wish to implement Phong shading (per fragment/pixel).

I've had a look at relevant tutorials online and there are two camps: one offers a simple Gouraud-to-Phong reshuffling of shader code which, while offering improved lighting, isn't truly per-pixel. The second does things the right way by utilising normal maps embedded within textures, but these are generated within a modelling toolkit such as RenderMonkey.

My questions are:

> 1. How I should go about programmatically generating normals for my
>    generated geometry, considered it as a vertex set? In other words, given a set of discrete polygonal points, will it be necessary to manually calculated interpolated normals?
> 2. Should I store generated normals within a texture as exemplified
>    online, and if so how would I go about doing this within code rather
>    than through modelling software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computing the lighting in the fragment shader on the intepolated per-vertex normals will definitely yield better results (assuming you properly re-normalize the interpolated normals in the fragment shader) and it is **truly** per-pixel. Although the strength of the difference may very depending on the model tessellation and the lighting variation. Have you just tried it out?

As long as you don't have any changing normals inside a face (think of bump mapping) and only interpolate the per-vertex normals, a normal map is completely unneccessary, as you get interpolated normals from the rasterizer anyway. Whereas normal mapping can give nicer effects if you really have per-pixel normal variations (like a very rough surface), it is not neccessarily the **right** way to do per-pixel lighting.

It makes a huge difference if you compute the lighting per-vertex and interpolate the colors or if you compute the lighting per fragment (even if you just interpolate the per-vertex normals, that's what classical Phong shading is about), especially when you have quite large triangles or very shiny surfaces (very high frequency lighting variation).

1. Like said, if you don't have high-frequency normal variations (changing normals inside a triangle), you don't need a normal map and neither interpolate the per-vertex normals yourself. You just generate per-vertex normals like you did for the per-vertex lighting (e.g. by averaging adjacent face normals). The rasterizer does the interpolation for you.
2. You should first try out simple per-pixel lighting before delving into techniques like normal mapping. If you got not so finely tessellated geometry or very shiny surfaces, you will surely see the difference to simple per-vertex lighting. Then when this works you can try normal mapping techniques, but for them to work you surely need to first understand the meaning of per-pixel lighting and Phong shading in contrast to Gouraud shading.

Comment: Excellent detail as usual, Christian. My normals don't change that much, but I wanted to do the job properly so had to check; the book misled me with the quote I posted in a comment to peachy below. I've just implemented Phong and the lighting looks fantastic now :) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Normal maps are **not** a requirement for per-pixel lighting.

The only requirement, by definition, is that the lighting solution is evaluated for every output pixel/fragment. You can store the normals on the vertexes just as well (and more easily).

Normal maps can either provide full normal data (rgb maps) or simply modulate the stored vertex normals (du/dv maps, appear red/blue). The latter form is perhaps more common and relies on vertex normals to function.

To generate the normals depends on your code and geometry. Typically, you use dot products and surrounding faces or vertexes for smooth normals, or just create a unit vector pointing in whatever is "out" for your geometry.

Comment: "The latter form is perhaps more common" Perhaps you're thinking of a form of normal compression, where the tangent-space normals are stored in two components. The third is reconstructed in the fragment shader with a simple square-root, since the normal is known to be unit-length, and the Z coordinate (the one dropped) is always positive in tangent-space.

Comment: @peachy: Not a requirement per-se, but definitely beneficial, hence my question. Quoting from OpenGL ES 2.0 Programming Guide: "The simplest way to do lighting per-fragment would be to use the interpolated vertex normal in the fragment shader and then move the lighting computations into the fragment shader. However, for the diffuse term, this would really not yield much better results than doing the lighting per-vertex. To really take advantage ... using a normal map to store per-texel normals can provide significantly more detail."

Comment: @KomodoDave You're confusing two different concepts. Adding normal maps is intended to provide more detail when used with per-pixel lighting, however, per pixel lighting works as expected without it; you simply don't get any detail beyond what's given in the geometry.